# Least Privileges for Windows Scheduled Tasks

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, powershell, permissions, scheduled-task

I want to configure a Windows Server 2012 R2 and a Windows User (Active Directory Domain) in a way that the user has least privileges to access (read) a windows scheduled task on a remote windows server.

As long as I use local admins (on the remote systems) everything works fine. But I don't want to use local admins for obvious reasons, so I tried configuring a non-admin user to access scheduled tasks on a remote maschine. The user X is a member of the remote local groups `Distributed COM Users`, `Performance Monitor Users`, `Performance Log Users`, `Remote Desktop Users`, and `Remote Management Users`. Additionally X is has `Execute Methods`, `Remote Access`, and `Enable Account` in WMI for the Namespaces `\Root\CIMV2` and `\Root\Mirosoft\Windows\TaskScheduler`. Also X has the permission to log on as a batch job.

When I log on with X on the remote server (powershell remoting) and run Get-ScheduledTaskInfo I get:

```
Category : PermissionDenied
Activity : Get-ScheduledTaskInfo
Reason : CimException
TargetName : PS_ScheduledTask
TargetType : Root/Microsoft/Windows/TaskScheduler/PS_ScheduledTask
```

Which tells me that X does not have the appropriate WMI permissions...

I'm out of ideas. Does anyone know how to configure a user with least privileges to access remotly running scheduled tasks?

Comment: Wouldn't be easier to _schedule a task_ that exports the state of the scheduled task in a file where the user has read access ?